# Garden label into Repeater to find my label

Tags: c#, asp.net

It is such that I have a Repeater with both label and Literal content, and that is how I got it into Repeater and I would like it being like shown at the side.

It appears with the error that tells me that it can not find my label or Literal

Repeater her:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterOpslag" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
            <div id="forslagbox" runat="server">
                <asp:Label ID="LabelBrugernavn" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Literal ID="LiteralLikesOpslag" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                <asp:Literal ID="LiteralDelete" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                <div style="margin-bottom: 5px; clear: both;"></div>
                <asp:Label ID="LabelText" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <div style="margin-top: 5px; clear: both;"></div>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <hr class="tall" style="margin: 7px 0;">
                </div>
            </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Default.aspx.cs here, It is in foreach which gives me problems that it will not print any of it at all.

```
RepeaterOpslag.DataSource = db.ForslagOpslags.ToList();
    RepeaterOpslag.DataBind();

    List<ForslagOpslag> forslagopslag = db.ForslagOpslags.ToList();
    foreach (ForslagOpslag item in forslagopslag)
    {

        var likesFjern = db.ForslagOpslagLikes.Where(a => a.fk_brugerid == Helper.ReturnBrugerId()).Count();

         LabelBrugernavn.Text = item.brugere.fornavn + " " + item.brugere.efternavn;

        LabelText.Text = item.text;

        if (likesFjern >= 1)
        {
            LiteralLikesOpslag.Text = "<a href='fjernsynesgodtom.aspx?id=" + item.Id + "&brugerid=" + Helper.ReturnBrugerId() + "' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>Fjern synes godt om</a>";
        }
        else if (item.brugere.Id != Helper.ReturnBrugerId())
        {
            LiteralLikesOpslag.Text = "<a href='SynesGodtOm.aspx?id=" + item.Id + "' class='btn btn-success btn-xs'>Like opslag - " + item.ForslagOpslagLikes.Count() + " synes godt om</a>";
        }
        else
        {
            LiteralLikesOpslag.Text = "<p class='label label-lg label-success'>" + item.ForslagOpslagLikes.Count() + " synes godt om</p>";
        }

        if ((item.fk_brugerid == Helper.ReturnBrugerId() || Helper.BrugerRank(Helper.ReturnBrugerId()) == 1))
        {
            LiteralDelete.Text = "<a href='slet.aspx?id=" + item.Id + "' class='btn btn-danger btn-xs'>Slet</a>";
        }

    }
```